# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

My xamarin application run on emulator and also run on my device when I attached with my PC. But when I create its apk and then install it crash after splash scree. I track the log and try to identify but failed. Please help me to sort it out. The log is mention below:

> 10:44:37 E mono : Unhandled Exception:
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String,
>   System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.String, System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]][],
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e while decoding custom attribute
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.MonoCustomAttrs:GetCustomAttributesInternal
>   (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type,bool)
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase
>   (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, Boolean
>   inheritedOnly) [0x00019] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes
>   (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, Boolean
>   inherit) [0x00040] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.GetCustomAttributes
>   (System.Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetOrCreateOperation
>   (System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription cd,
>   System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi, System.Reflection.MethodInfo
>   serviceMethod, System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute oca,
>   System.Reflection.MethodInfo endMethod, Boolean isCallback,
>   System.Type givenServiceType) [0x0022d] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.FillOperationsForInterface
>   (System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription cd, System.Type
>   exactContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, Boolean isCallback)
>   [0x00134] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContractInternal
>   (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType,
>   System.Type serviceTypeForCallback) [0x002d4] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract
>   (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType,
>   System.Type serviceTypeForCallback) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract
>   (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract
>   (System.Type contractType) [0x00000] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract
>   (System.Type contractType) [0x00017] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateDescription ()
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel]..ctor (System.Type
>   type) [0x00033] in :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel]..ctor
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding,
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].Initialize
>   (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding,
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel]..ctor
>   (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding,
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x0003f] in
>   :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel]..ctor
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding,
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at AceVqbzServiceClient..ctor
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding,
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>
> 10:44:37 E mono : at System.Refle

Comment: You need to add reference to the system.runtime version 4.0.0.0 it's not able to load it

Comment: In my visual studio, it showing that it is already added. Even when I remove these references my project still running in emulator and not give any error

Comment: You need to enable fusion logs and it will give u more info on which assembly is not getting loaded . Also check the bin folder what all assemblies are there

Comment: No, but System.Runtime.Serialization.dll is here showing in red color

Comment: Please enable fusion logs this is very very simple issue

Comment: How can I enable fusion log , kindly let me know ? I am stuck in this issue from many hours

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework are you targeting?  4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: @Mick .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution?

Comment: @Mick Yes, I have 5 project in a single solution

Comment: It's clear from the exception that your application is attempting to load .NET 4.0 assemblies and failing.  Check the versions of all your projects.

Comment: I checked, all are 4.5.1 and PCL project is on 4.5.0

Answer (score 1):

The application is crashing because some of code is remove at time of linking the assembly. So, you need to identify that code or remove if you can other wise the other option is to **customize your linker** according to your error log.

To run my apk, I skip/exclude three dll's from linking at the time create apk. i.e. **System.Collection, System.Runtime, System.Runtime.Serialization.** To do same just right click on your Droid project and go to properties and choose Android Option tab as you seen in below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking assemblies? Xamarin includes the functionality to link assemblies to reduce APK size, however not all assemblies seem to allow.

To confirm, I would change the debug settings to be identical to the release ones or to disable linking for the release. (Build > Droid Project Options)

Comment: Yes, I know about it. I have tried to set linking to none but still get same error.

Comment: @AjaySharma i would suggest that you rename your question to "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair" as this is your exception,Also Trying to use stack trace pays well in these situations

Comment: @Virgil What kind of help "Stack Trace" can do in this ?